# Make Web Modal looks like mac finder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, macos

I make a website looks like mac os. I just want to make notice board looks like mac finder.
(There has a folder list, when I click it, it will open like finder.)

How can I make it looks like mac os (plus animation if can)?
I cannot find it.

I just do it with overriding bootstrap modal, but it is not well designed.

Is it impossible? Or if someone know how to do it or know some great module , Please tell me.

I really thank all of you.

I have no idea to coding it. My web modal looks like this with animation.

[image]

Comment: It's very possible. But you'd need to provide some sort of code so that we can help you. Try to do it, then post your code.

Comment: you can do it easily with trial and error with CSS. idk if there's a library for it right now, but the effect is definitely possible

Comment: Please give me some hint or great examples..

Comment: I've updated my answer with a quick example of what I have been able to do in 30 minutes of work.

Comment: this seems sketchy, like something you'd build if you were creating spam or trying to trick someone in to downloading something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be 99% impossible if you have 0 coding experience. The people on this website won't do it for you.

I'll try point you in the right direction.

Firstly, you will want to look at [some tutorials on HTML and CSS](https://www.codecademy.com/catalog/language/html-css). You will need to become fairly proficient with the two in order to create the visual of the Finder window.

You would want to use Bootstrap as this will simplify the styling of it.

[Here is an example of what I have been able to do in roughly 30 minutes.](https://codepen.io/lachiekimber/pen/pZpmPb)

---

**Inspiration to use when trying to replicate the finder window**

The following link is an example of what some designer did a little while ago. http://www.alessioatzeni.com/mac-osx-lion-css3/

Essentially he was able to re-create the look and feel of Mac OS using `HTML`, `CSS` and some `JS`. Look at his code for inspiration.

The next link is a CodePen that someone made for the old OS finder: https://codepen.io/paddykontschak/pen/JALeB

Comment: I think my question is wrong... sorry..
I make some samples but it was not pretty so I do not upload..

Comment: Thats okay, samples that are not pretty are better than nothing! We are here to assist you with your code.